# embedded mysql query inside unix_timestamp

Tags: mysql

Why is this not working

```
...
) as Data
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Data.DateTime) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SELECT DateTime from  mytable WHERE ID = $inputID)
```

It seems to work if I don't have this embedded sql statement, but the sql statement works on its own also so I'm not sure why the combination is causing a failure.

It's telling me

> check to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'SELECT DateTime from mytable WHERE ID = 1008)' at line 1

Comment: Just a hunch, but try surrounding the SQL with (): WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Data.DateTime) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((SELECT DateTime from  mytable WHERE ID = $inputID))

Comment: now how can I close this question, can you answer so I can set your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surrounding the SQL with additional parens ():

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Data.DateTime) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((SELECT DateTime from mytable WHERE ID = $inputID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
...
) as Data
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Data.DateTime) <= (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateTime) from  mytable WHERE ID = $inputID)
```

If DateTime has type DateTime than you can also use:

```
...
) as Data
WHERE Data.DateTime <= (SELECT DateTime from  mytable WHERE ID = $inputID)
```